# How to show all 'questions' and 'answers' in the _form.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a table `questions`(:id, :description) with model  "question.rb" and a table `answers`(:id ,:question_id, :answer_descriptin) with model "answer.rb".

How can I show all questions and their answers in one page within a form partial like an questionnaire or an exam?

any idea?

Comment: Load the question and answers in the controller, expose them as instance variables, and pass them to the partial? It's not clear what *isn't* working with what you've tried so far since we can't see that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a has_many association to the Question model:

```
has_many :answers
```

And then you can use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) to display sub forms for each answer within a question.

You might also want to look at [Qwester](https://github.com/reggieb/qwester)

Comment: Thank you!! It's very helpful~

Comment: I configured the Qwester(it's wonderful), but I don't know how to show the questionaires to users. How can users answer these questionaires?

Comment: Questionnaires will be listed at the root of the point where you mount qwester. If you've used the example in the README, they will be at /questionnires